# Is $\{(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2: z_1^2+z_2^2 +1 \ne 0\}$ a domain of holomorphy?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I'm wondering whether $\{(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2: z_1^2+z_2^2 +1 \ne 0\}$ is a domain of holomorphy. It seems that I don't get what this definition really means, so any hints about ways of thinking/intuition would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $\Omega$ your domain and define $E:=\Bbb C^2\setminus\Omega$.

Then you can prove that $E$ is *thin* in $\Bbb C^2$ thus every holomorphic mapping on $\Bbb C^2\setminus E=\Omega$ *locally bounded* (that is $\forall U\subset\subset\Bbb C^2$ such a function is bounded on $U\setminus E$) extends holomorphically across $E$ (hence to an entire function).
As pointed out by AG learner, the mapping $f(z_1,z_2)=1/(z_1^2+z_2^2+1)$ is not locally bounded (not even locally $L^2$, which is a weaker condition, enough to get the conclusion).
So we can't argue that $\Omega$ is a domain of holomorphy so far.

Eventually, the conclusion is given by definition of domain of holomorphy (see book by M. Range "Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables",II 2.1). The above defined function is holomorphic on the whole $\Omega$ and it is completely singular at every boundary point $p\in E$, hence $\Omega$ IS a domain of holomorphy.

Comment: If I understand correctly, referring to M.Range's book, E becomes an analytic subset, hence by thm. I.3.8, a thin subset?

Comment: Sounds perfect to me since $E$ is the zero set of a holomorphic polynomial, that is, it's a analytic set, so it's thin by the theorem you mentioned. Hence you can get the result in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joe!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: The second paragraph is totally wrong. How do you extend $1/(1+z_1^2+z_2^2)$ on $\mathbb C^2\setminus E$ across $E$?

Comment: Ouch, you are right, my conclusions holds only if the holomorphic function $h\in\mathcal O(\Bbb C^2\setminus E)$ is locally bounded (or -weaker- it's locally in $L^2$), which of course is not the case of every holom. function $h$.

Comment: @AGlearner: thanks for pointing out, I corrected my answer.